# When using Japanese IME and pressing Ctrl + Caps Lock, how do you make it toggle to half-width alphanumeric, not full-width?

Tags: windows-7, windows, language, japanese

I'm using Japanese IME on Windows 7, and I like to use Ctrl + Caps Lock to toggle between English and Japanese.  In the past, when it would toggle to English, it would be half-width alphanumeric.  Suddenly it's changed itself to switch over to full-width alphanumeric, even if it were just toggled to Japanese from half-width.  How can you change this back?  I didn't see anything in the properties window for the Japanese "keyboard" in Region and Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you mean <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> and not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Caps lock</kbd>.

Second: You do what you want like this:

Control panel > Region and Language > Keyboard and Languages > Change Keyboards > Japanese > Microsoft IME > Properties > 'Editing' Tab > Editing operation and behavior > Key Template > Check `IME Standard`

Now `Ok` your way out of all the open windows and the next time you toggle with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps lock</kbd>, your English will be Half-width

Comment: It didn't work, unfortunately.  Thanks though.

Comment: It's actually very strange I've tried it before posting and it worked just fine. And now I feel myself pretty stupid for my overconfident answer.

Comment: No, dude, I've upvoted your answer.  If you tried it and it worked, then it's a good answer.  There was just something different going on on my particular machine.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting another answer just in case someone finds
that the accepted solution does not work.

I found a working solution for my case (Windows 10 Home, ver. 1903). 
The source is a Japanese [website blog](https://osamushi.jp/caps-lock/). 
Basically, the solution is to change the Advanced Keyboard Settings.

In Windows 10,

1. Open Settings
2. Click "Time and Language"
3. On the left side of the window, click "Language"
4. On the right side of the window, under "Preferred Languages",
   click "日本語" ("Japanese") and then click "Options"

[image: step4: Language Settings → Preferred Languages → 日本語 → Options]

5. Scroll to the bottom; under "Keyboards",
   click "Microsoft IME" and then click "Options"

   [image: step5: Language Options ⇒ Keyboards → Microsoft IME → Options]
6. Scroll to the bottom (again); click "Open Advanced Settings"
7. In the new window, go to the "AutoCorrect" tab
8. Pay attention to the bottom half: "Full-width/Half-width characters". Choose "Alphabet" on the left side, then choose "Always use Half-width" on the right side.

   [image: step8: AutoCorrect → Alphabet → "Always use Half-width"]
9. Click "Apply" / "OK" to finalize the change.

Comment: Microsoft, in its infinite wisdom, has decided to do away with advanced IME settings. At least they are nowhere to be found, at least not where you used to find them. I am using Windows 10 Professional, build 19045. Sorry for the pointless rant.